# Is $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}\to S_4:(1\,0)\to(1\,2)(3\,4),(0\,1)\to(1\,3)(2\,4)$ a homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know the answer is "yes" because the cycles $(1\,2)(3\,4)$ and $(1\,3)(2\,4$ are disjoint and thus commute, but I don't understand how commutativity alone satisfies the homomorphism property

Comment: The question does not really make sense. You are speaking about a function defined on $\mathbb{ Z\times Z}$, but you only give the images of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. How is the function defined for all the other values?

Comment: I think he means to ask "Is there a homomorphism with this prescribed mapping?"

If there is then it's unique because he's described it on a generating set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the function by $$f:\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{Z} \to S^4:(n,m)\mapsto (12)^n(34)^n(13)^m(24)^m.$$ Then $f(1,0)f(0,1)=f(0,1)f(1,0)$ because, as you said, the permutations commute, and $f(n,m)=f(1,0)^nf(0,1)^m$ by definition.

So $$f((a,b)+(c,d))=f(a+c,b+d)=f(1,0)^{a+c}f(0,1)^{b+d}=f(1,0)^af(1,0)^cf(0,1)^bf(0,1)^d=f(1,0)^af(0,1)^bf(1,0)^cf(0,1)^d=f(a,b)f(c,d)$$ and $f$ is indeed a homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

A categorical answer:

$\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ is a coproduct "$\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}$" in the category of *abelian* groups (and it isn't one in the category of groups). A homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow A$ is then determined, and determined uniquely, by its values on the summands of the coproduct; that is, a homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow A$ is equivalent to a pair of homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow A$... for an *abelian* group $A$. Each homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow A$ is of course determined, and determined uniquely, by its value on $1$ ($\mathbb{Z}$ is a *free* abelian group on a single generator).

Therefore if the subgroup of $S_4$ generated by those permutations is an abelian subgroup, then the homomorphism you'd like to define exists.